# Volley JSONObject request Parsing Response returns No Value for

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a RESTful API running in my local machine which returns a response in JSON (Actually this JSON is the response of nodejs Soap client request) depending on the request. For this particular case I receive POST request from an Android client and return the following response:

```
{
    QueryAcctBalResponse: {
        BalExDtoList: {
            BalExDto: [{
                BalID: "xxxx",
                AcctResID: "xxxx",
                AcctResName: "xxxx",
                BalType: "xxxx",
                Balance: "xxxx",
                EffDate: "xxxx",
                ExpDate: "xxxx",
                UpdateDate: "xxxx"
            }, {
                BalID: "yyyy",
                AcctResID: "yyyy",
                AcctResName: "yyyy",
                BalType: "yyyy",
                Balance: "yyyy",
                EffDate: "yyyy",
                ExpDate: "yyyy",
                UpdateDate: "yyyy"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is each time I try to parse that response and display this information in android (Particularly "AcctResName"). I get **org.json.JSONException: No value for BalExDto**. I use Volley Libray in android to parse Json and i used Jsonobject request.

Request Code.

```
JsonObjectRequest sq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, balanceUrl, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("BalExDto");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Toast.makeText(CheckBalance.this, ""+jsonObject.get("AcctResName"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            pd.hide();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Response", "Response_TAG: "+response);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says - you are parsing `BalExDto` wrong. `BalExDto` is not direct child of `response`. So you have to parse `QueryAcctBalResponse` and `BalExDtoList` and then you can get `BalExDto`. Because `BalExDto` is inside `BalExDtoList` and `BalExDtoList` is inside `QueryAcctBalResponse`.

```
JsonObjectRequest sq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, balanceUrl, request, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        JSONObject queryAcctBalResponse = response.getJSONObject("QueryAcctBalResponse");
        JSONObject balExDtoList = queryAcctBalResponse.getJSONObject("BalExDtoList");
        JSONArray jsonArray = balExDtoList.getJSONArray("BalExDto");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Toast.makeText(CheckBalance.this, ""+jsonObject.get("AcctResName"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        pd.hide();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("Response", "Response_TAG: "+response);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't have a JSON Array, you have a JSON Object.

First of all, you need to get the JSON object from your API response,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("QueryAcctBalResponse")
```

and inside that JSON object is the JSON Array.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("BalExDtoList");
```

Answer (score 0):

`BalExDto` array is not the direct child of the response. It is inside `BalExDtoList` which is inside `QueryAcctBalResponse`object. You can not directly access any node in the JSON, you need to traverse the full path before you could access them.

You need to get the array like below

```
JSONObject queryAcctBalResponse = response.getJSONObject("QueryAcctBalResponse");
JSONObject balExDtoList = queryAcctBalResponse.getJSONObject("BalExDtoList");
JSONArray jsonArray = balExDtoList.getJSONArray("BalExDto");
```